# Haskell Functional composition error

Tags: haskell, function-composition

I might be asking something very stupid and the answer might be very simple as "the implementor chose it that way", but here I go.

To add two numbers we can use any style: `(10+) 4` or `10 + 4` or `(10 + 4)`.

while if we have two functions, say `add10` and `multiply5` 
and compose them to make one function out of it, say `add10andMultiply5` 
then
`add10.mul5 10` seems to give an error while
`add10.mul5 $ 5` will work and
`(add10.mul5) 5` will work and
`add10andMultiply5 5` will also work.

Any comments why the first one should not work ? 
Please enlighten me. Thanks.

Comment: `10 (+4)` won't work, because it means "apply the function `10` to the argument `(+4)`, and `10` is not a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functional composition in Haskell has lower precedence than function application. So `add10.mul5 10` is parsed as `add10 . (mul5 10)`. Now, the type of `.` is given as:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

The first argument (`add10`) has type `Int -> Int`, so we can establish that b is `Int`, and hence `.` expects its second argument to be of type `a -> Int`. But instead it's of type `Int`. Adding the `$` changes the association, and means that instead the function composition is done before applying the composed function to 10.

Everything works in your first example because you're not composing functions, you're just applying them. The equivalent in this case would be trying to do `(10+) . 4`, which you will observe also fails.

Answer (score 7):

It's an issue of precedence, or how tightly different operations bind.

In Haskell, function application has the highest precedence (tightest binding), followed by function composition, followed by function application with `$`. It's a bit like arithmetic, where exponentiation has highest precedence, then multiplication, then addition, so that

```
1 + 2 ^ 4 * 3 + 4 * 3
```

is parsed as

```
1 + ((2 ^ 4) * 3) + (4 * 3)
```

In your examples, you have

```
add10 . mul5 10
```

which will be parsed as

```
add10 . (mul5 10)
```

because the function application binds tightest. This doesn't work, because `mul5 10` is a number and `add10` is a function, and composition only works between two functions.

On the other hand,

```
add10 . mul5 $ 10
```

is parsed as

```
(add10 . mul5) $ 10
```

because function composition has higher precedence then application with `$`.